# Java/Jython - how to relate unfound classes to specific jar files

Tags: java, class, jython, package

This also puzzled me when experimenting with the Lucene package... but this is an example now I'm trying to get into HTTP/JSON/URL stuff using Java. In fact I use Jython... as this is not an SSCCE I've left it in the (more concise) Jython.  Java users should have no difficulty understanding.

I got some code from SO explaining how to send a JSON object using Java:

```
import javax.json
import org.apache.http.impl.client as httpclient

httpClient = httpclient.HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
try:
    request = javax.json.HttpPost("http://yoururl") # Rubbish: see below
    params = javax.json.StringEntity(json.toString())
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    request.setEntity(params)
    httpClient.execute(request)
# handle response here...
except Exception, ex:
    # handle exception here
    print ex
httpClient.close()
```

when I try to run this, I first get "class not found" for HttpClientBuilder.
A bit of googling leads me to https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi... so I look at this page and think: it's probably the "HttpClient" download I need... so I download and extract the 10 jar files. I guess that I need to include httpclient-4.4.1.jar.  Correct.

The next thing "class not found" is ConnectionReuseStrategy: I investigate and then include httpcore-4.4.1.jar.  Correct.

After this I get "class not found" for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.  Guessing, I include commons-logging-1.2.jar. Correct.

After this I get

> 'javapackage' object has no attribute 'HttpPost'

This Jython message means that I guessed the package "javax.json" for HttpPost incorrectly.
So I google "HttpPost" and find it is a member of org.apache.http.client.methods.  This doesn't tell me which jar file to include next... I have to guess!

My question is: supposing you can find the (likely) package where a class comes from, can you find how the package relates to an actual jar file?  As I say, this was a big puzzle for me with Lucene, and now with all this Apache HTTP stuff.

Comment: If you use the Maven import / add dependency feature in IntelliJ / Eclipse, it will find all the right dependencies / jar files for you.

Comment: thanks... "Maven" is a word I hear from time to time.  I won't say it scares me but it makes me sigh and think "yet another thing to learn".  I'm sure I'll have to, probably now, but is there not another, non-Maven, way?  I do indeed use Eclipse, but supposing I wasn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com) (or http://findjar.com as some would have it) !

***later***
Not systematic, however: it does not appear to involve an automated system.  You have to submit "likely candidate" jars.  I submitted the elasticsearch jar.  But Lucene also appears to be missing.  Have started reading about Maven.  Sigh.